# Javascript in PHP if Statement

Tags: javascript, php

I have follow code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE['lg'])) {
echo 'cookie da<br/><br/>';
echo '<div style="margin-top: -25px; margin-bottom: -25px; height: 375px; overflow: hidden"><iframe width="650" height="400" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/aXlGiKzzZDA?rel=0" frameborder="0"> </iframe></div>';
}
else {
echo 'cookie nichtda<br/><br/>';
setcookie('lg');

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">

echo 'something';

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>

}

?>
```

How can I get these Javascript codes get to work here? Is it even possible?

EDIT:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            FB.init({appId  : '121689674645582', status : true, cookie : true,xfbml  : true});

            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
                window.top.location = "http://bla.com";
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).mousemove(function(e){
                    x=e.pageX ; y=e.pageY;
                    $("#like").css({top: (y - 4) + "px", left: (x - 4) + "px"});
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Can I also just echo this whole code inside PHP statement?

Comment: echo them like you do the html

Comment: There is actually no JavaScript in your example. Just PHP and HTML and you cannot directly put HTML in a PHP code block. You can `echo` it or put it outside, but not inside, like you did. That's a [syntax error](http://codepad.org/suWp6cco): `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 11`.

Comment: You can `echo` them with proper quoting/escaping, just as you did for the HTML above.

Comment: I edited my question, what about the code which I added?

Comment: *"Can I also just echo this whole code inside PHP statement?"* You could, but instead of generating HTML with PHP through `echo`, you should "embed" the PHP in HTML. E.g. `<div><?php echo $someVar; ?></div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE['lg'])){
?>
cookie da
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="margin-top: -25px; margin-bottom: -25px; height: 375px; overflow: hidden">
    <iframe width="650" height="400" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/aXlGiKzzZDA?rel=0" frameborder="0"> 
    </iframe>
</div>
<?php
} else {
?>
cookie nichtda
<br/>
<br/>
<?php
setcookie('lg');
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

and the second part:

```
<?php ?>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            FB.init({appId  : '121689674645582', status : true, cookie : true,xfbml  : true});

            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
                window.top.location = "http://bla.com";
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).mousemove(function(e){
                    x=e.pageX ; y=e.pageY;
                    $("#like").css({top: (y - 4) + "px", left: (x - 4) + "px"});
                });
            });
        </script>
<?php ?>
```

and one more way:

```
<?php

echo<<<THEJSCODE
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            FB.init({appId  : '121689674645582', status : true, cookie : true,xfbml  : true});

            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
                window.top.location = "http://bla.com";
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).mousemove(function(e){
                    x=e.pageX ; y=e.pageY;
                    $("#like").css({top: (y - 4) + "px", left: (x - 4) + "px"});
                });
            });
        </script>
THEJSCODE;//no spaces before keyword 

?>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `<?php ?>`. Also, since the OP seems to be a beginner, it would probably very helpful for him if you explained your solution(s).